# IF statement in R. Add new elements in new column if conditions met

Tags: r, dataframe, analytics

I'm trying to add a column in the data frame where the new element in the new column has the value of "1" if the conditions are met for that particular row.

To check the condition I am iterating through another reference data frame.

```
county_list = (df$county_name[df$wolves_present_in_county==1 & df$year==2015])

for (i in df$county_name) {
  for (j in county_list) {
    if (df$county_name[i]==county_list[j])
    {
      df$wolvein2015 = 1
      break
    }
  }
}
```

[Error in Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1ui8.png)
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4BM5.png)

Comment: One of the values in `df$county_name` or `county_list` is `NA`, and `R` does not know how to compare `NA` to other things, so your `if` condition fails.

Comment: Thanks for that, I checked for the NA values with anyNA(county_list) and anyNA(df$county_name) but both returned FALSE.

Comment: Are you updating the whole column `df$wolvein2015 = 1` for each row?

Comment: Yeah i was making that mistake, i updated it though and now making it df$wovlvein2015[i] = 1. Still the same issue though.

Comment: @curiousneel can you try the solution i posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want in base R.  Here is an example using mtcars:

```
cars <- mtcars
cars$new <- ifelse(cars$cyl == 4 & cars$mpg > 30, 1, 0)
```

The new column is added with 0/1's based on conditions of 2 other variables.

BTW, because R is a vectorized paradigm, you should only use `for` loops as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, following is the original problem that I intend to do: 

Let us identify the counties with wolves present in 2015. Create a variable that is equal to 1 if
wolves were present in the county in 2015. In other words, this variable should be coded equal to
1 for all years in the data if a county has wolves in 2015.

Comment: Right, so just create your compound logical `ifelse` statement like in the example above and you will generate the new variable with values conditioned on the logical outputs.

Comment: Thanks, this approach helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(wolvein2015 = +((year == 2015 & !is.na(year)) &  
         as.logical(wolves_present_in_county) & !is.na(wolves_present_in_county)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this adds a column with all values as 0, how do i do the following : 

"Let us identify the counties with wolves present in 2015. Create a variable that is equal to 1 if
wolves were present in the county in 2015. In other words, this variable should be coded equal to
1 for all years in the data if a county has wolves in 2015."